# Setting Colors in Altair Layered Chart

Tags: python, altair, vega-lite

Similar to [Setting colors in Altair charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71218914/setting-colors-in-altair-charts) I am using a layered chart and I like to set excplicit colors. Somehow, when I use the solution from the answer, my colors are always changing to some arbitrary colors. I wonder, if anyone knows, why this happens and how to force altair to use the colors given in the colors array.

Here a test example:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.movies()
colors = ['#170c3b', '#fa8d0b']


plot = alt.Chart(source).mark_line().encode(
    x=alt.X("IMDB_Rating", bin=True),
    y=alt.Y(
        alt.repeat("layer"), aggregate="mean", title="Mean of US and Worldwide Gross"
    ),
    color=alt.datum(alt.repeat("layer")),
).repeat(
    layer=["US_Gross", "Worldwide_Gross"]
).configure_range(
        category=alt.RangeScheme(scheme=colors)
)

plot.show()
```

Here the colors from the array:

| #170c3b | #fa8d0b |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Here the plot with changed colors:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `category=alt.RangeScheme(scheme=colors)` should be `category=alt.RangeScheme(colors)` instead.

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.movies()
colors = ['#170c3b', '#fa8d0b']


plot = alt.Chart(source).mark_line().encode(
    x=alt.X("IMDB_Rating", bin=True),
    y=alt.Y(
        alt.repeat("layer"), aggregate="mean", title="Mean of US and Worldwide Gross"
    ),
    color=alt.datum(alt.repeat("layer")),
).repeat(
    layer=["US_Gross", "Worldwide_Gross"]
).configure_range(
        category=alt.RangeScheme(colors)
)

plot
```

yields:
[image: plot]